# write to memoerystream using epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

I have this assembly that basically creates an empty excel file using EPPLUS library. The file is created directly to desk, but i want first to write it in a memoerystream and then save the memoerystream to desk. I have this so far.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplicationXLSX
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Createxlsx("XLSX");

        }


        public static void Createxlsx(string filename) 
        {
             FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("C:\\ConsoleApplicationXLSX\\" + filename + ".xlsx");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            //create a package 
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
            {
                package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet");


                package.Save();

            }
        }


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`package.SaveAs(ms)`

That should fill your stream with the excelfile-content.

Comment: ms cannot convert from 'system.io.memoerystream' to 'string'

Comment: sorry - you already filled the memorystream - i overread that - after `package.Save();` just call `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` and then write to File `File.WriteAllBytes(yourfilename, ms.GetBuffer());`.